# standard deviation - missing values

Tags: statistics

A data set with $14$ observations contained the following values:
$$2, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 7, ?, ?$$
Where $?$ represents a missing value.

## $1$. The standard deviation of the full data set (including the missing values) is:

A) Lies between $0$ and $1$
.

B) Lies between $1$ and $2$
.

C) Lies between $2$ and $10$
.

D) Lies between $10$ and $20.$

E) Impossible to determine with the given information.

Comment: Well, if the missing values are around 15, then the standard deviation should be pretty small (I think something like 4, though I didn't do a careful calculation). But what if the missing values are 1,000,000?

Answer (score 1):

If there are no constraints on the last two numbers then it is impossible to determine what the standard deviation will be. If you put in 1,000,000 for each of the missing data points you will get a very large standard deviation (something around 360,000).

The answer is E

Comment: why is this answer downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

**user273635** has given the essential idea. In case you’d like to see more computational details, make the missing values $21$ and $30+14x$. Then the sum of the $14$ values is $14(15+x)$, so the mean is $15+x$, and the standard deviation is

$$\begin{align*}&\sqrt{\frac1{14}\left((13+x)^2+10x^2+(8+x)^2+(x-6)^2+(13x+15)^2\right)}\\
&\qquad=\sqrt{\frac1{14}\left(182x^2+420x+494\right)}\\
&\qquad>\frac{13x}4
\end{align*}$$

if $x\ge 0$, since $\frac1{14}>\frac1{4^2}$, and $182>13^2$. Thus, the standard deviation can be made arbitrarily large by choosing $x$ large enough.